# Perl - Differences in BEGIN an non-BEGIN block

Tags: perl

I have a question regarding the const declaration in perl, 
and could not figure out the differences, please kindly 
point out what are the differences.

Below is the code:

```
BEGIN {
  *SIZE = sub() { 2 };
}  
*ITEM = sub() { 10 };

print 'size=', SIZE, "\n";
print 'item=', &ITEM, "\n";
```

Now is the question,
  Why

```
  print 'item=', &ITEM, "\n";
```

line must have a '&' in front of ITEM,
  But

```
  print 'size=', SIZE, "\n";
```

line do not need to have a '&' in front of SIZE.

And I know the BEGIN block is run at compile time.

Answer (score 7):

Because the BEGIN block is run at compile time, the compiler knows about the assignment to `*SIZE`, while the assignment to `*ITEM` hasn't happened yet.

Because the compiler doesn't know about `*ITEM`, calls to `ITEM` are ambiguous, thus you must prefix it with an `&`. Otherwise, the compiler thinks it could be a "bare word" -- an unquoted string.

If you [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html#strict-subs), the compile will assume that bare words are functions.

[`use constant`](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) may also be a better way to declare constants, rather than doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
BEGIN {
  *SIZE = sub() { 2 };
}  
*ITEM = sub() { 10 };

print 'size=', SIZE, "\n";
print 'item=', ITEM, "\n";
```

would get processed as follows if there was no error:

- Compile file.

  - Compile `BEGIN` block.

    - `*SIZE = sub() { 2 };`
  - Execute `BEGIN` block.

    - `*SIZE = sub() { 2 };`
  - Compile `*ITEM = sub() { 10 };`
  - Compile `print 'size=', SIZE, "\n";`
  - **Compile `print 'item=', ITEM, "\n";`**
- Execute file.

  - **Execute `*ITEM = sub() { 10 };`**
  - Execute `print 'size=', SIZE, "\n";`
  - Execute `print 'item=', ITEM, "\n";`

Note how `print 'item=', ITEM, "\n";` is compiled before the sub exists. If `ITEM` existed as a sub, that would be allowed. But `ITEM` doesn't exist as a sub. In the absence of any other meaning, identifiers are bare words, and bare words are compiled into a string with the same value.

```
>perl -E"my $x = ITEM; say $x;"
ITEM

>perl -E"my $x = 'ITEM'; say $x;"
ITEM
```

That is, unless you specifically ask Perl to do otherwise:

```
>perl -E"use strict; my $x = ITEM; say $x;"
Bareword "ITEM" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

That means you need to make `ITEM` look like a sub call.

```
print 'item=', ITEM(), "\n";
```

`&ITEM` also works, since `&` is the instruction to tell Perl to ignore prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

The & prefix unambiguously means "this is a user-defined subroutine call coming up next". You can omit it when you are using parens after your function name and your function name doesn't conflict with a built-in, or if you've declared/defined your function before you use it and the name doesn't conflict with a built-in.

[Continuing read here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=428024)

And check @Sean McMillan response.